# Microsoft Graph - get Outlook Calender events - 403 Forbidden

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, http-status-code-403, microsoft-graph-calendar, outlook-api

I tried to receive all events for an Microsoft 365 User. It's a business license and a add an App with all User/Mail/Calendar Permissions (also consent granted) to Api permissions.

When running this command or some similar like in the documentation I got 403

```
Client error: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/events` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` re  
  sponse:                                                                                                                                  
  {"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}}
```

What did I do wrong? I also tried the Graph Explorer (with logged in user).

Comment: How are you getting the token? Please add those details...Also check the token in https://jwt.ms and see if you have those peemissions

Answer (score 1):

Are the permissions you are assigning delegated or application permissions?

If you are using application permissions for your App Registration then you need to give access on the user's  calendar to the app (probably by using a new service principal on exchange online).

If you are using delegated permissions then you should check the access token you are getting for validation in jwt.ms

Bear in mind that Graph explorer with logged in user needs different permissions than your App Registration. ( it's a different app registration altogether )

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I had the same issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1165285/microsoft-graph-get-outlook-calendar-events-403?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1168253#newest-answer-comment

The fix was to remove all the other permissions and just give it
[image: Permissions from Azure Portal]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.